# How can I implement a retry option using Jenkins pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, dsl

Currently in build flow plugin we use following approach. This code will retry twice.

```
    programs_create_servers_retry_count=2
    retry(programs_create_servers_retry_count) { 
            build( "create_virtual_servers",j_SL_data_center_local: programs_create_servers_dc_1,j_random_id_local: random_id)
    }
```

How can do the same Jenkins Pipeline plugin?

Comment: Its still the same retry(n) { } block. Check this pipeline step retry https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-retry-code-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `retry` method in Jenkins DSL : https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times

Example piece of code will look like that:

```
stage('stageName') {
   try {
     ...
   } catch(error) {     
     retry(3) {
        do smth
     }
   }
}
```

Where number 3 is number of attempts to retry.